# The compatibility of Android and Ubuntu mobile SW

Tags: android, glibc

Android uses `bionic` but Ubuntu uses `glibc`. How do they keep the compatibility in Ubuntu for Android? Does Ubuntu for Android use bionic? Or it gives up Android NDK compatibility?